# Class 'Google_Service_Docs' not found (Google Docs API quickstart.php)

Tags: php, google-docs, google-docs-api

I am following [this guide](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/quickstart/php?authuser=1#troubleshooting) to authorize access of my website to the Google Docs API but I am having trouble getting through step 4.

When I run this command in the SSH command line as per step 4 the guide:

```
$ php quickstart.php
```

nothing happens within the command line, although I have an error log in the working directory and the following appears:

```
[08-Feb-2019 09:47:23 America/New_York]
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Google_Service_Docs' not found in /home/***/***/composer/quickstart.php:12
Stack trace:
#0 /home/***/***/composer/quickstart.php(62): getClient()
#1 {main}
thrown in /home/***/***/composer/quickstart.php on line 12
```

For reference, line 12 in the code (which you can view in full [in the official Google guide](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/quickstart/php?authuser=1#troubleshooting)) is line 5 in the code below:

```
function getClient()
{
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName('Google Docs API PHP Quickstart');
    $client->setScopes(Google_Service_Docs::DOCUMENTS_READONLY);
    $client->setAuthConfig('credentials.json');
    $client->setAccessType('offline');
...
```

I have already successfully installed the Sheets API before so there shouldn't be any problem in steps 1 or 2, and step 3 is just copy-paste so I have no idea where the problem could be on my end.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a problem with the name of the scope. I am trying to find a list of valid scopes for [Oath2 of Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes) but with no success.

Answer (score 0):

```
$client->setScopes(Google_Service_Docs::DOCUMENTS_READONLY);
```

^ Seems to be obsolete and the guide is not up to date, use this instead:

```
$client->setScopes(https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents);
```

Comment: Nevermind, this DOES allow me to create a valid access token, but then I run into exactly the same error on line 64 with "$service = new Google_Service_Docs($client);" I think there is simply a bug at Google's side right now