# Determining the status of the Google Docs API?

Tags: google-docs-api

I'm trying to determine the status and reliability of the [Google Docs API](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/).
So far I've found a few red flags.

- Undocumented data structures, looks self describing but once analysing real data questions arise
- [Zero response to any issues](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:555502%2B)
- [Already outdated documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54595029/class-google-service-docs-not-found-google-docs-api-quickstart-php)

What signals can we use to determine if Google Docs API will be available and kept up to date with Google Docs?